# cassandra nodetool repair - how to schedule properly?

Tags: cassandra

Im putting together a 16 node cassandra cluster (replication factor 2) and want to setup a schedule for `nodetool repair`. **gc_grace_seconds** is at the default.

Two questions:

1. My first impulse is to setup a cron job for each machine and attempt to manually randomize the timing around a one week schedule. Is there a better way?
2. Does `nodetool repair` have to be run on *every system* or *every # systems/replication factor systems*? (IE for my 16 nodes with replication factor 2 - 8 systems - one of each pair)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not randomize it.  Your best bet is to schedule the repairs so they don't stomp on each other.

You should use the -pr option on each node when running repair.

If you're using Cassandra 2.1 you have the option for incremental repair which will speed things up considerably.

RF=2 is also a recipe for disaster.. quorum queries will fail if a node is unavailable.  I recommend RF=3.

Comment: On a small cluster (12-16 nodes) - on new reasonable hardware.. will there truly be failures that often?

Comment: It's not just about node failures.  It's about cluster configuration changes, restarts, network partitions, power failure, rack failure.  Additionally, as I mentioned, if you're using QUORUM - your queries will fail if only one node goes down.

Comment: @JonHaddad what is the purpose of using -pr option?

Comment: From "nodetool help repair": -pr, --partitioner-range.  Use -pr to repair only the first range returned by the partitioner.  Otherwise you initiate a repair on the entire cluster.

Comment: In the last line of your answer, should that say "RF=2 is a recipe for disaster..." as indicated by OP's RF? I've personally been burned by by setting RF=2 and QUORUM CL.